# What kind of work the Apostles have?

Tags: 2-thessalonians

2 Thessalonians 3:8

> nor did we eat anyone’s food without paying for it. On the contrary,
>   **we worked night and day**, laboring and toiling so that we would not be
>   a burden to any of you

My conclusion: 
The Apostles get money from someone as their boss as a salary for their night and day work, laboring and toiling, then they use the money to pay their food.

So the question is :
what kind of work those Apostles do night and day in order to get money?
to whom (who is the boss) do they work night and day ?

Comment: Paul is only talking about himself, Silas and Timothy here. Paul made tents.

Comment: I agree with @curiousdannii. Paul made it clear that he worked and Luke's narrative in Acts makes it clear that Paul was a tentmaker by trade. It is also clear from the narrative that Paul was self-employed and had no 'boss'.

Comment: Sorry, I am not asking just Paul, but also other Apostles. _"**we** worked night and day"_

Comment: @curiousdannii, do you mean that the example shown by "them" where "them" 
 are Paul, Silas and Timothy who are to be imitated by the elect ? God said : _"live according to the teaching you received from **us** : me, Silas and Timothy"_ ..... _"**we** : me, Silas and Timothy worked night and day_" .

Comment: Yes, in this case the most natural interpreter is that Paul is mostly talking about himself, Silas, and Timothy, not all the apostles. Note that at other times Paul was given an income for his ministry work.

Comment: It needs also to be considered that in this place (as he does in others) he is using the 'ministerial' 'we' and is commenting primarily , if not exclusively, upon his own personal situation.